# Problem getting access to an array variable in a javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have the following script

The page can also be seen [in action here](http://www.tdsoft.se/examples/glenn2.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Version: 1.0.0 -->
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Flot Examples</title>
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
   <body onLoad="myFunction()">


            <a href="javascript:printing()">Show All Coverafdedge</a>
            Show: </div>        

    <p><span id="x">0</span>, <span id="y">0</span></p>


      <p><input id="enableTooltip" type="checkbox">Enable tooltip</p>



<script type="text/javascript">

var datasets = [];

var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


function myFunction(){

    loadXMLDoc("parsers.json",handleXML);
}
var checkState = function(xmlhttp, callback) {
//document.write(xmlhttp.readyState);
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    callback();
  } else {
    // Check back again 1 sec later
    setTimeout(checkState, 1000);
  }
};

function handleXML() {
checkState(xmlhttp, function() {

    var txt=xmlhttp.responseText;
    datasets = [];
    var datasetsCounter =0;
    var secondPos = 0;
    var aPosition = 0;
    var currentCharacterLocation =0;
    var textLeft =txt;
do
  { 
    aPosition = textLeft.indexOf("#");
    secondPos = textLeft.indexOf(";");
    evaluedText = textLeft.substring(aPosition+1,secondPos);
    datasets[currentCharacterLocation] = eval("(" + evaluedText + ")");
    currentCharacterLocation++;
    textLeft = textLeft.substring(secondPos + 1);
  }
while (textLeft.indexOf("#") > -1);


 }); 
} 


function printing(){
for(var g =0; g < datasets.length; g++ ){
document.write(datasets[g].cover.data + "__");
}
}

$(function () {
    var d1 = [];
    var d2 = datasets[0].cover.data;
    // a null signifies separate line segments
    var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1, d2, d3 ]);
});

</script>       
</body>     
</html>
```

Now to my problem that I have with the variable "datasets", if I for example try to print out "datasets[0].cover.data" (Like I do in my function printing(), I can do that (Try yourself clicking on the link on that page). But when I try to use the variable inside the

"var d2 = datasets[0].cover.data", I get the error that its datasets[0].cover.data is not defined :S

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here? =)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the function in $(function() { ... }); is running when your body onload is called.  You need to do something like

```
$(function () {
    loadXMLDoc("parsers.json", function () {
        handleXML(); // possibly add a callback to this function which calls the remaining code in this function

        var d1 = [];
        var d2 = datasets[0].cover.data;
        // a null signifies separate line segments
        var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

        $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d1, d2, d3]);
    });
});
```

And then remove the call from body onload

Answer (score 0):

Your function is running on document ready, but before the `datasets` variable is populated.

Move the code to the end of the callback function:

```
do
{ 
...
}
while (textLeft.indexOf("#") > -1);

var d1 = [];
var d2 = datasets[0].cover.data;
// a null signifies separate line segments
var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

$.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1, d2, d3 ]);
 }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised the array at the time you call "var d2 = datasets[0].cover.data".

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is nothing in `datasets` at that point, so there is no datasets[0], so of course there can be no `datasets[0].cover.data`!

Ask yourself: How is datasets supposed to be populated, and where and when is that to occur?

It gets populated in `handleXML` but that only happens *after* the `var d2` line.

Also, using `eval` is generally frowned upon, see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) for details.